# Всплытие jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять что не так.
Вроде запретил всплытие события, но "не работает".

Под всплытием имею ввиду, что от потомка события передаются родителям и т.д.
Так вот, мне нужно чтоб события выполнились только у потомка и на нем все закончилось.

В результате хочу получить клик по "header-mobile-menu". Клик по "mobile-layer" НЕ должен считаться как клик по "header-mobile-menu".

Привожу пример с песочницы - [jsfiddle][1]

```
<div class="header-mobile-menu">
  <div class="mobile-layer">123</div>
</div>

$('.header-mobile-menu').click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert(123);
});
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

События "всплывают" от детей к родителям. Вызов `event.stopPropagation();` должен быть  в обработчике события внутреннего элемента.

```js
$('.mobile-layer').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(123);
});
$('.header-mobile-menu').click(function(event) {
  console.log(456);
});
```

```css
.header-mobile-menu {
  border: black solid 1px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 30px;
}

.mobile-layer {
  border: black solid 1px;
  background: lightpink;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-mobile-menu">
  <div class="mobile-layer">123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: День добрый!
Не додумался поставить вызов у потомка...
Большое спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: @РасулМансуров На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: @РасулМансуров "Спасибо" на хлеб не намажешь. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Конечно!
Готово)